# Gmail labels and filters

Tags: gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have a bunch of filters set up to channel certain emails; label them and skip the inbox.

However, if I reveive an email that doesn't fit the filter criteria, and I label it manually, I would like it to operate under those filter specs, ie, disappear from the inbox in this case.

Is that possible? The only way I can find is to go into filter settings and "apply to all conversations" every time.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of "`Labeling`" the mail, i.e. using the label icon, you can "`Move`" the mail to a label (using the *Folder* icon).
This will tag the mail with the right label **and** archive it (no more in the inbox).

Comment: When using the Android version of gmail I still have to do the label and archive as a two step process.